# group by like string

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I have a table `employee` in this table i have `id company_name employee_id`

```
1 abc  2015_acb_1 
2 abc  2015_acb_2 
3 abc  2015_acb_3 
4 abc  2015_acb_4
5 xyz  2016_xyz_9 
5 xyz  2017_xyz_2 
5 xyz  2016_xyz_3 
5 xyz  2019_xyz_5
```

I want to select unique string such as from employee table

```
_abc_
_xyz_
```

i have try `select employee_id where employee_id like %_%;` its not giving as i expected

Comment: Are you always looking for the characters between the two `_` characters? Or always for three characters starting at the sixth?

Comment: _ is a wildcard character (exactly one) so '%_%' will match strings without '_'. You can escape it like: `... WHERE employee_id LIKE %\_% ESCAPE '\';`

Comment: `split_part(employee_id, '_', 2)` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(employee_id FROM 5 FOR 5)
FROM employee;
```

> some of record contains 3 to 4 _ symbol and position is different

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('_',
                       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(employee_id, '_', 2), '_', -1),
                       '_')
FROM employee;
```

Comment: what is 5 FOR 5 ?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(` of `employee_id` field starting `FROM 5`th symbol `FOR 5` chars length `)`.

Comment: sir some of record contains 3 to 4  _ symbol  and position is different

Comment: like 2017_HCL_012346_3_4 and 2016_TCS_375_875_2

Comment: What do you want from these strings then?

Comment: @deviya My fortune-telling ball is under repair right now. If you want the solution for all possible variants you MUST show these all possible variants. And - place them into your question text ("edit" link under it), not in a comment. The best way you will formulate some rules applicable for any value which allow to understand what part of the value does you need.

Comment: @deviya: what is the result you expect for `2016_TCS_375_875_2` - `TCS`? `375`? `875`? And what about

Comment: i would like to get just word from employee table word  like `_HCL_, _TCS_, _xyz_` etc  common word which contains all `employee_id`

Comment: @deviya Check... if underscores are not significant, remove CONCAT wrapping.

Comment: @deviya: are those "common words" always after the first underscore? Can there be more than that? e.g. `2017_HCL_TCS_012346_3_4`